# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Either class [coconut.User] is not a domain class or

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

So I'm getting this error. I'm sure it has something to do with incompatible versions of stuff, but I have no idea what I did wrong.

I'm doing it through sdkman as I should be... `grails --version` gives me `3.2.11`.

```
2017-06-29 22:17:15.406 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : IllegalStateException occurred when processing request: [GET] /user
Either class [coconut.User] is not a domain class or GORM has not been initialized correctly or has already been shutdown. Ensure GORM is loaded and configured correctly before calling any methods on a GORM entity.. Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
        at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
        at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
        at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Either class [coconut.User] is not a domain class or GORM has not been initialized correctly or has already been shutdown. Ensure GORM is loaded and configured correctly before calling any methods on a GORM entity.
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.stateException(GormEnhancer.groovy:427)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.findStaticApi(GormEnhancer.groovy:296)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.findStaticApi(GormEnhancer.groovy:292)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.currentGormStaticApi(GormEntity.groovy:1341)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.getCount(GormEntity.groovy:627)
        at coconut.UserController.create(UserController.groovy:5)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
```

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Download the ziped project below.
2. `grails clean; grails run-app`
3. And in a second terminal: `curl localhost:8080/user`

#### Expected Behaviour

I don't get that error.

#### Actual Behaviour

I get that error.

#### Environment Information

- **Operating System**: Ubuntu 17.04
- **Grails Version:** 3.2.11
- **JDK Version:** 1.8.0_131

#### Example Application

[coconut-test.zip](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/files/1113962/coconut-test.zip)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
```

into your "dependencies" block in build.gradle

Comment: You're the best!